# Array.map() Producing Strange Results

Tags: jquery

I have a set of textarea elements on page that all share the same class name.

I'm attempting to retrieve their values into an array like:

```
var deal_dcon_recs = $('.deal_dcon_text').map((i, {value}) => value);
```

Seems pretty simple to me.

But I'm experiencing the strangest results.

The array I get is an array of the html objects, not just the string value.

From this troubleshooting code:

```
var deal_dcon_recs = $('.deal_dcon_text').map((i, {value}) => {console.log('value', value); return value;});
console.log('deal_dcon_recs', deal_dcon_recs);
```

I get this output:

[image]

What in the world am I missing here?

Comment: I think your lambda has to return `value.value`

Comment: value.value is undefined.

Comment: sorry, I misread the destructuring expression, because I don't do js on a daily basis anymore. Anyway my expectation is that it is iterating over the jquery objects not an array. I think you need to call the jquery accessor method (`val()` I think).

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: @TimSeguine the jquery .map iterates dom elements, `.map(i, el)` so you could do `return $(el).val()` but won't be as efficient as other methods.

Comment: @Nick your code works fine, but on the console.log you're outputting a jquery array-like - either call `.toArray()` on the result or `.get()`: `var deal_dcon_recs = $('.deal_dcon_text').map((i, {value}) => value ).get();` if you want to use jquery or one of @ikiK options if you want to stick with js.

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah, I forgot it iterates over dom objects instead of jquery ones. The important thing to point out is what you already said that it is not in fact Array.map that he is calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current logic within `map()` is correct. The issue is because you're missing a call to `get()` after the `map()` in order to return the array that's generated, not a jQuery object:

```js
var deal_dcon_recs = $('.deal_dcon_text').map((i, {value}) => value).get();
console.log(deal_dcon_recs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="deal_dcon_text">Lorem ipsum</textarea>
<textarea class="deal_dcon_text">Dolor sit</textarea>
<textarea class="deal_dcon_text">Amet consectetur</textarea>
<textarea class="deal_dcon_text">Adipscing elit</textarea>
```

Comment: You're right about .get(). I don't think I've ever been privy to what that did. All I can find on .get() is a method for retrieving HTTP results: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: This is the reference in the docs for that specific call: https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2. `map()` will create an array (containing strings in this case) and place it inside a jQuery object. As we want the array, not the jQuery object we call `get()` to retrieve the underlying object.

Answer (score 2):

Just a another way of using loop and plain JS, to simplify things...

```js
let result = []
document.querySelectorAll(".deal_dcon_text").forEach(el => result.push(el.value))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<textarea name="textarea" class="deal_dcon_text" placeholder="Enter the text...">1</textarea>
<textarea name="textarea" class="deal_dcon_text" placeholder="Enter the text...">2</textarea>
<textarea name="textarea" class="deal_dcon_text" placeholder="Enter the text...">3</textarea>
```

Or using map and spread operator ...:

```js
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll(".deal_dcon_text")].map((i) => i.value);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<textarea name="textarea" class="deal_dcon_text" placeholder="Enter the text...">1</textarea>
<textarea name="textarea" class="deal_dcon_text" placeholder="Enter the text...">2</textarea>
<textarea name="textarea" class="deal_dcon_text" placeholder="Enter the text...">3</textarea>
```

BTW spread operator will work on jquery also:

```
let result = [...$(".deal_dcon_text")].map((i) => i.value);
```

Comment: Or using jquery, to "simplify things... :) "  `var deal_dcon_recs = $('.deal_dcon_text').map((i, {value}) => value ).get();`

Answer (score 0):

For me map work with an array and selector is an object:

you could try:

```
$('.deal_dcon_text').toArray().map....
```

Comment: You're right. I am mostly a back-end JS developer and didn't realize that jquery selector returns an object (instead of an array). Seeing it had a map() function available, I assumed it was an array. SMH Of course your solution works.